# Update User Locations after every 10 sec - get location form mysql

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, google-maps

I am building an app which gets user data from mysql and show them on the map, 
From my android app, I update the table (lat,lon) every 10 seconds, Now I want to update their locations on google map (web app) **without refreshing the map or page**

Here is my code:

**This function loads on page refresh**

```
function initMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 33.7167, lng: 73.0667},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
 mapOptions);

    makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {

    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //display(data[i]);
            displayLocation(data[i]);
        }
    });
//window.setInterval(initMap, 15000);   
}
```

**makeRequest Function**

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
} else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
}
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        callback(request);
    }
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();

}
```

**get_location.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$l= array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$l[] = $row;
}
$j = json_encode($l, true);
echo $j;
//return $j;
?>
```

**Display Location Function**

```
function displayLocation(location) {

            var contentString ='<div class=\"chapter-bubble\">' 
+'<strong>Name: ' + location.username + '</strong>'+'<br/>'+'<strong>Phone: 
</strong>'+location.phone_number +'</strong>'+'<br/>'+'<strong><a 
href=\"sendsms.php?phone_number=' + location.phone_number + '&username=' + 
location.username +'\"> Send SMS</a> </strong>'+'<br/></div>' ;
            //window.alert(location.name);

            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), 
parseFloat(location.lon));
            //window.alert(position);

            var image;
                if (location.is_safe=="0")
                {
                    image = new 
google.maps.MarkerImage('placer/not_safe.png', null, null, null, new 
google.maps.Size(40, 40));
                }
                else if (location.is_safe=="1")
                {
                    image = new 
google.maps.MarkerImage('placer/yes_safe.png', null, null, null, new 
google.maps.Size(40, 40));
                }

                //window.alert(image);



            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: location.username
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
}
```

What I have done is add this line **window.setInterval(initMap, 5000);** at the end of initMap function but it loads the map, I just want to change the locations only without refresing page or map. 
Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array and add the markers to the array. Before updating the new markers the markers need to be removed from the map. This can be done by using the clearMarkers method as given below

Declare this at the top of the js file

```
var markerArray = new Array();
```

Add the following method in the js file

```
function clearMarkers()
 {
     for(var j=0, len = markerArray.length; j<len; j++)
        {
         markerArray[j].setMap(null);     
        }
        markerArray = new Array();
 }
```

Separate the code from initMap and create a new method called updateLocation

```
function updateLocation()
{
  makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {

        clearMarkers();

        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                //display(data[i]);
                displayLocation(data[i]);
            }
        });
    window.setInterval(updateLocation, 15000); 
}
```

It will be called from initMap method

```
function initMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 33.7167, lng: 73.0667},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
 mapOptions);

  updateLocation();    
}
```

In the Display Location Function add the marker to the array after creating it:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: location.username
   });

 markerArray.push(marker);
```